# Apache Runs HTML File As Script?

Tags: apache

I'm having a bit of an issue with setting up an Apache installation for a project I inherited. The original installation the project uses is Apache 2.2, but I'm currently using 2.4, and since the folder/filename and config options have changed a bit, I'm not sure what's causing my scripts to behave this way.

I have a script that's setup to execute from my cgi-bin directory which, among other things, generates an HTML file and after everything is complete, it uses "Location:whoami.html" to navigate to this page. The page is located within cgi-bin when it is created. However, instead of this page being served client-side, it creates an Internal Server Error message, and the log suggests that the page was interpreted as a script because it says:

```
(13)Permission denied: AH01241: exec of '/var/www/cgi-bin/whoami.html' failed
[client xxx.xx.xx.xx:xxxxx] End of script output before headers: whoami.html, referrer: http://xxx.xx.xx.xx
```

So why is it interpreting this page as a script, if in fact, that is what it's doing? The old server has the same directory configurations for the cgi-bin directory, but it serves the page as it's supposed to without error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue was that the script that creates the file wasn't running because I forgot to add the www-data user to the /etc/sudoers file... easy fix that I really should have thought of before.